# Why are there two mechanisms to remove/hide disks in Linux?

Tags: linux, block-device

I'm using Linux from external drive. I don't want it to see primary disk with Windows at all. In the past I have been doing that by writing 1 to `/sys/block/devices/sd*/device/delete` (writing from memory).

But with other laptop, which has NVMe disk, the structure is different and I have to use `/sys/block/devices/nvmep01/device/device/remove` (again, from memory). (External disks connected by USB still follow the previous pattern) Why are there two ways? Can't I use just the one? Is one of them deprecated? (I haven't checked if sd* has remove available as well)

(Distribution is Ubuntu 22, if it matters)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways because they are driver-specific commands (there is no generic "remove this device" command on Linux), and of course the two examples deal with different device types handled by different device drivers. (It's sort of how Windows has the StorAhci.sys driver for SATA and StorNvme.sys for NVMe.)

The point is that `sd*` doesn't just mean "disk", it **specifically means "SCSI disk",** i.e. a device that speaks the SCSI command set and is handled by the SCSI driver. It's used for USB disks because those are always SCSI under the hood.

On modern Linux, the SCSI driver also happens to be used for ATA disks because it turned out to be more robust to do it that way (SATA shares concepts with SCSI and there's an 1:1 translation for most SCSI-ATA commands). But until just a few years ago, ATA disks had their own driver and an internal HDD would've been named `hd*` instead (/dev/hda, etc) – and they would have had their own structure under /sys as well.

NVMe, on the other hand, is *vastly* different from SCSI and ATA, so while Linux did also have a similar `sd*` translation layer for a short while, it was ultimately found better to let NVMe disks have their own device type and to have tools directly speak NVMe commands. Therefore NVMe disks are named `nvme*`.

(Internally, both SCSI and NVMe also have more complex structure than just "cable goes to disk, disk holds sectors"; for example, SCSI has 'LUNs' and NVMe has 'namespaces', both of which allow a single disk to present as multiple but in different ways; and the corresponding Linux drivers end up representing them in very different ways for probably a combination of many reasons – so it is not surprising to see differences in the way their /sys paths are laid out.)

It also seems that for NVMe you're starting off with a *partition* device rather than a whole-disk device, so when you go "upwards" through the `.../device` symlinks in /sys, there are naturally two levels from 'partition' to 'whole disk' to 'controller' instead of just one.

As for `delete` vs `remove`, it's probably just a random inconsistency resulting from different people implementing it in different kernel subsystems at different times.

Comment: While your explanation seems reasonable if we talk about *devices themselves*, here we probably talk about *partitions*. The code that handles partitioning is the same for SCSI and NVME and ATA and virtio block and probably MTD and others, so there shouldn't be at least "delete vs remove" inconsistency.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: They're not removing the partition; they're going through the `device` symlink to its parent device.

Comment: "just a few years ago" sounds like a massive understatement. The switch from `hd*` to `sd*` by default happened 10-15 years ago depending on what distro you use. A few years ago, the old (non-libata, `hd*`) infrastructure was deleted from the kernel source, but it was already unused for a long time unless you happen to run on 20+ years old hardware not supported by the "modern" system.

Comment: There is absolutely a generic "remove this device" command: `rm /dev/whatever`. This won't remove it from the sysfs knowledge of device topology etc., but it will make it so there's no way to inadvertently read from or write to it, format it, etc. which seems like the most likely motivation for "removing" it.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Original reason for this question was that in the past Ubuntu updater (or one of the packages, possibly grub) could modify MBR or other pieces on Windows disk, making it un-bootable. I wanted to prevent it, `sys/block delete` did the trick (autostart or crontab), I'm not sure whether `rm /dev/...` would suffice.

Comment: Have you considered switching to UEFI firmware mode where such issues generally don't occur in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure? Original installer of Ubuntu installed it in UEFI mode, modifying my Windows original disk (EFI partition?), which I want to avoid. So no, I don't believe they don't occur in the first place. Thanks nevertheless.